# How to write the INNER JOIN in dql

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my select and it works in workbench fine, but how did i write the INNER JOINS for doctrine?

```
$qb = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT oh.objektnummer, oh.idSubunternehmer, oh.datum, oh.typ, oh.outbox
            FROM MBSAllgemeinBundle:ObjektHistory oh
            INNER JOIN MBSAllgemeinBundle:Objekt o ON o.objektnummer = oh.objektnummer AND o.idSubunternehmer = oh.idSubunternehmer
            INNER JOIN MBSAllgemeinBundle:Subunternehmer s ON s.subunternehmernummer = o.id_subunternehmer
            INNER JOIN MBSAllgemeinBundle:SubunternehmerUser su ON su.id_subunternehmer = s.subunternehmernummer
            WHERE su.idUser = 1"
    );
```

Comment: You mean how to write an INNER JOIN with the query builder ? Because your query is already in DQL.

Comment: I got the error Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON', so i think in my INNER JOIN i have to remove the ON, but in the first JOIN i have two parameters which are needed. How should i remove the ON

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not selecting the whole ObjectHistory entities, instead of the single columns?

Comment: a user is related to one or many subunternehmer and a subunternehmer have on or many objekts and the objekt-history should only be views for this objekts

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax in your repository :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('oh')
        ->select('partial oh.{id, objektnummer, idSubunternehmer, datum, typ, outbox}')
        ->innerJoin('MBSAllgemeinBundle:Objekt', 'o', 'ON', 'o.objektnummer = oh.objektnummer AND o.idSubunternehmer = oh.idSubunternehmer')
        ->addSelect('o')
        // other INNER JOIN
        // other INNER JOIN
        ->where('su.idUser = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', 1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::select() in /var/www/symfony/src/MBS/AllgemeinBundle/Repository/ObjektHistoryRepository.php line 30   thats the response from symfony

Comment: Call directly the `createQueryBuilder()` method. I edit my answer.

Comment: this i got as SQL: SELECT partial oh.(id, objektnummer, idSubunternehmer, datum, typ, outbox), su FROM MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\ObjektHistory oh INNER JOIN MBSAllgemeinBundle:Objekt o ON o.objektnummer = oh.objektnummer AND o.idSubunternehmer = oh.idSubunternehmer INNER JOIN MBSAllgemeinBundle:Subunternehmer s ON s.subunternehmernummer = o.id_subunternehmer INNER JOIN MBSAllgemeinBundle:SubunternehmerUser su ON su.id_subunternehmer = s.subunternehmernummer WHERE su.idUser = :id

Comment: and this is the error from symfony:     [Syntax Error] line 0, col 18: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_CURLY_BRACE, got '('

Comment: ATM it's an error in the rest of your code. What I give you is just an example of how to use "INNER JOIN" in the query builder. You should put this code in a method of your repository.